# как работает функция compose() в javaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Допустим есть фрагмент когда:

```js
const startTicking = () =>
setInterval(
    compose(
        clear,
        getCurrentTime,
        serializeClockTime,
        convertToCivilianTime,
        doubleDigits,
        formatClock("hh:mm:ss tt"),
        display(log)
    ),
    oneSecond()
)
startTicking()
```

Как в таком случае работает функция `compose`? Пример из [книги](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049579.do), это какая-то стандартная для ES6 или реализация паттерна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [такой паттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), но данная функция, видимо, не его реализует, а что-то вроде труб bash'a.
Нет, в JS нет такой стандартной функции.

В книге "Learning React: Functional Web Development with React and Redux", откуда, вероятно, взят пример, в этой главе изучают функциональный подход.

На будущее - указывайте контекст, а то кто-то не захочет гуглить и догадываться, а просто влепит минус и закрывашку. И будет прав.

Answer (score 3):

речь идет 100% про книгу "Learning React: Functional Web Development with React and Redux"
функция compose() описывалась в разделе "Композиция", пару страниц назад от этого примера

```
const compose = (...fns) => (arg) => 
  fns.reduce((composed, f) => f(composed),arg)
```